# How to connect on-prime database in synapse using link services in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-synapse

I am following the steps from this guide to connect to the on-prime database using spark.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/data-sources/apache-spark-sql-connector

tried this code:

```
servername = "XXXXX"
dbname = "poplesdb"
url = servername + ";" + "databaseName=" + dbname + ";"
dbtable = "Test"
user = "test\user" 
password = mssparkutils.credentials.getSecret('xxxx','xxxxxxx')
```

I got this error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:mssparkutils.credentials.getSecret.
: com.twitter.finagle.NoBrokersAvailableException: No hosts are available for XXXX.vault.azure.net:443, Dtab.base=[], Dtab.local=[]. Remote Info: Not Available
```

I am trying this connection test since days. please anyone help me?
Here my screen shots of linked service . I need to connect the source inside retail database
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
> z:mssparkutils.credentials.getSecret. :
> com.twitter.finagle.NoBrokersAvailableException: No hosts are
> available for XXXX.vault.azure.net:443, Dtab.base=[], Dtab.local=[].
> Remote Info: Not Available

Given error indicates that a request failed because no servers were available. This typically occurs under one of the following conditions:

- The cluster is actually down. No servers are available. - A service discovery failure. This can be due to a number of causes, such as the client being constructed with an invalid cluster destination name or a failure in the service discovery system (e.g. DNS).

A good way to diagnose NoBrokersAvailableExceptions is to reach out to the owners of the service to which the client is attempting to connect and verify that the service is operational. If so, then investigate the service discovery mechanism that the client is using.